# How to dispatch work among several processors?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I have a class which performs some data processing:

```
class Processor
{
    public Processor() {
        // Load lot of data
    }
    public string GetResult(string input) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

I need to implement a service which exposes HTTP API to this class. I use Owin and Microsoft.AspNet.* libs to host HTTP Web API. For each request it creates a new thread to handle it, but I cannot instantiate `Processor` on every request as it takes enormous time to load some data in its constructor. Also I cannot reuse one instance from different threads as it was not designed to be thread safe. But I can instantiate several instances of `Processor` on service start, and then dispatch work among them. Say I allow up to 20 concurrent HTTP requests for my service. I create 20 instances of `Processor` and add Busy flag to the class:

```
class Processor
{
    public bool Busy { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

I wrote `Dispatcher` class like this:

```
class Dispatcher
{
    readonly Processor[] _processors;
    readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public Dispatcher(int maxProcessors)
    {
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxProcessors);
        _processors = new Processor[maxProcessors];
        // Instantiate Processors, etc...
    }

    public string GetResult(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            _semaphore.Wait(); // Surplus requests will wait here.
            Processor processor;
            lock (_processors)
            {
                // It is guaranteed that such processor exists if we entered the semaphore.
                processor = _processors.First(p => !p.Busy);
                processor.Busy = true;
            }
            var result = processor.GetResult(input);
            processor.Busy = false;
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can basically call it through `Dispatcher` in ApiController:

```
public class ServiceController : ApiController
{
    static Dispatcher _dispatcher = new Dispatcher(20);

    [Route("result")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Result(string input)
    {
        return _dispatcher.GetResult(input);
    }
}
```

Is it implemented correctly for my purpose?
I tested it and it works, but I wonder if I reinvented the wheel and .NET Framework has somewhat ready to use for my case, or if it could be implemented easier.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312

Comment: @SLaks it is not quite clear how to use `BlockingCollection` in my case as I need not only distribute work items but also collect results. Supposing I have some number of workers that consume from `BlockingCollection` I should somehow wait until corresponding result is ready and get it. It is solvable but I am not sure it is easier than this...

Comment: Looks like a very good implementation to me. I'm not aware of a .Net configuration that would handle your use-case.  If the number of processors will always be equal to the maximum concurrent requests, perhaps the semaphore is redundant (a lower-level semaphore would already protect your processor pool from starvation); However, If the Processor class is CPU-bound rather than IO-bound, you might want to adjust your Processor pool size to the amount of processing cores available, that way you minimize context-switching between concurrent threads and might get better overall performance.

Comment: @BlueStrat if you mean some internal AspNet semaphore that maintains maximum number of concurent requests, then yes, I did an additional semaphore intentionally, to prevent thread-safety errors in case of service misconfiguration.

Comment: Using semaphores are pretty low level, and I myself have not used them since I was writing in C++.  I have done several multi-threaded apps that do not use them and I have never had an issue.  Basically just a loop that will spin up a new thread as long is one is available.

Comment: @ChrisBartlett either I did not understand your suggestion, or you did not understand my problem.

Comment: @greatvovan Sorry I was not clear.  You can spin up your thread at start up, and keep track of them as they are being used.  They can register to events in the calling class that can either give them new work or move on to the next thread if it is still busy.  All this can be handled using the System.Threading library without ever creating a Semaphore.  .Net has made it relatively easy to manage threads now.

Comment: @ChrisBartlett it is still unclear. How to determine that a thread is busy? How to delay oncoming requests in case all processors/threads are busy without Semaphore? You told this could be handled using System.Threading and I would appreciate it very much if you show me how. Could you express your idea in code rather than words?

Answer (score -1):

Basically in your class that is going to be run in the thread, create an event and event handler.  The object that then spins up this task can register to that event.  When it is raised by the task, (in this case you would raise the event when it is done) you can do something, ie. give it more work.

Create your events in the class that will be run in the child thread:
        `public event TaskCompleteEventHandler OnComplete;
        public event TaskErrorEventHandler OnError;`

Register to your events in the object that is spinning up the classes:

```
task.OnComplete += TaskComplete;
task.OnError += TaskComplete;
```

Create the function in the calling class that will handle the event:

```
public void TaskComplete()
{
//give the thread more work
}
```

Comment: I am realizing deeper and deeper that you misunderstood the problem. In my case I must have a single entry point from where I would be able to dispatch work. This entry point is method that handles requests to specific URL of web service and this method is called by different threads (most likely) simultaneously. There is no any limited set of items to process, I have to process incoming request ASAP and return the result.